# How to rename lines of files according to text in different file?

Tags: batch-file, batch-rename

I have multiple files like **test1.html, test2.html ... testn.html** and so on and in the same folder i have **names.txt** with all names for that **test{n}.html** files.
How can i loop through **names.txt** file and according to lines from it rename all html files?

**names.txt** structure like:

```
randomName 
NameRandom 
test 
Name
...
```

Comment: what is the format of `names.txt`?

Comment: already updated

Comment: is `randomName` supposed to be the name for `test1.html` and `NameRandom` the name for `test2.html`?

Comment: Yes, that's correct

Comment: So, to be clear, you're wanting to rename `randomName.html` to `NameRandom.html` and `test.html` to `Name.html`, is that correct? Or do you want to rename all `.html` files with names beginning with `test` and followed by one or more digits, to each of the names listed in `names.txt`? If the latter, are you guaranteeing that the same number of files are listed as exist in the directory?

Comment: i want to rename first test1.html => randomName.html, test2.html => NameRandom.html, test3.html => test.html and so on, numbers of files and names in the file are the same

Comment: Please take action and leave feedback to new answers. Consider accepting the best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will want to use a combination of `FOR` and `SET /a` to get this done. You would essentially increment a counter with `SET /a` inside a FOR loop that read the names.txt file, renaming the files based on the counter value and line entry.

```bat
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
SET counter=0
FOR /F "usebackq tokens=* delims=" %%f IN (names.txt) DO (
  SET /a counter=!counter!+1
  ECHO.N:!counter!
  REN "test!counter!.html" "%%f.html"
)
```

To perform variable manipulation within a loop you also need Delayed Expansion enabled (`setlocal enableDelayedExpansion`).

Comment: There is just one small problem: the incrementing doesnt work

Comment: revised to add delayed expansion

Comment: Be sure to vote up the answer if it solves your issue

Comment: I wouldn't use `tokens=*` and `usebackq`. Do you understand what you write? The OP may need filenames starting with spaces (which is something I fully disagree). There are also some other minor improvements to make better your code. See my answer below (will post in a moment).

Comment: re `tokens=*`, he provided only mock information, so while there don't appear to be spaces in the data yet, that doesn't mean there won't be. I personally use spaces in most file names, so assume there will be spaces.

Comment: re `usebackq`, I use it for several reasons within most of my own batch files, but include it when helping others script so if it's a class project their instructor is more likely than not going to be able to identify whether they wrote it themselves.

Comment: Is your "do you understand what you write" dig intended to demonstrate the welcoming and respectful environment that SE is supposed to be?

Comment: That was not used to be unfriendly or unkind. I asked because you don't need/use `UseBackQ` here.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```bat
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "testn=0"
set "extension=html"

for /F "delims=" %%A IN (names.txt) do (
    set /a "testn+=1"
    if exist test!testn!.%extension% (
        echo Processing test!testn!.%extension%
        rename "test!testn!.%extension%" "%%A.%extension%"
    ) else (
        call:finish
    )
)
goto:finish

:finish
echo Finished renaming^^!
pause
exit /b
```

In additional to the other answer, this would be *slightly* faster *if* the file contains more lines than `test*.html` files.

The extension is changeable/custom to whatever.

Comment: This double-loop would also result in an increasing number of errors for each subsequent file since the only way it succeeds in using the next filename is by erring out when trying to use the initial series of filenames from the FOR loop. test3.html would have 2 rename errors prior to being named test.html, and test999.html would have 998 errors before being renamed. This assumes that none of the files were actually renamed to a previous "test#.html" which would fail to use the correct new name.

Comment: The only caveat I see would be if someone deleted a file in the middle of the group.  If there are 12 input files and number 7 was deleted, it will leave test8 through test12 unchanged.